# How to Integrate Qt4 qm files into binary using cmake and QRC?

Tags: localization, qt4, internationalization, translation, cmake

I have a Qt4 CMake project and I'd like to integrate the QM files for i18n into the output binary. These are the rules I have so far for generating the TS and QM files:

```
set(myapp_TRANSLATIONS
    i18n/myapp_de.ts
)

set(FILES_TO_TRANSLATE
    ${myapp_SRCS}
    ${myapp_MOC_HDRS}
)

QT4_CREATE_TRANSLATION(QM_FILES ${FILES_TO_TRANSLATE} ${myapp_TRANSLATIONS})
QT4_ADD_TRANSLATION(QM ${myapp_TRANSLATIONS})
```

I tried the following to add the QM files to the executable:

```
add_executable(myapp ${myapp_SRCS} ${myapp_MOC_SRCS} ${myapp_RCC_SRCS} ${QM})
```

This is the initialization from main.cpp:

```
QTranslator qtTranslator;
qtTranslator.load("qt_" + QLocale::system().name(), QLibraryInfo::location(QLibraryInfo::TranslationsPath));
app.installTranslator(&qtTranslator);

QTranslator appTranslator;
appTranslator.load("myapp_" + QLocale::system().name());
app.installTranslator(&appTranslator);
```

However, `strings mypp` shows that the translations are not going into the binary.

**Update:** I added each qm file to a `i18n/translations.qrc`:

```
<!DOCTYPE RCC><RCC version="1.0">
  <qresource prefix="/resources">
    <file>myapp_de.qm</file>
    <file>  ...   .qm</file>
  </qresource>
</RCC>
```

and using

```
QT4_ADD_RESOURCES(myapp_QM_RCC_SRCS i18n/translations.qrc)
```

and adding `myapp_QM_RCC_SRCS` to the executable dependencies.

But this fails during build time thanks to the fact that CMake does a shadow build (building outside the source dir) but parses the QRC files for dependencies expecting the referenced files relative to the QRC file (nice feature but there's no make rule how to build the QM file at that location). The QM files are in `${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}` (where they belong using shadow building) but expects it in `${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}` (where non-generated files should be - so both locations would be correct, depending on situation).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I had the exact same problem. I came up with the following solution:

Create a QRC file that contains only the expected QM files, and give it a different prefix so it won't conflict with your other resources:

```
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/translators">
    <file>myapp_en.qm</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

Add a CMake rule to copy the QRC file to the output directory and then another rule to run the resource compiler:

```
# Change 'myapp_en' to be the base file name of the qrc file.
SET( trans_file myapp_en )
SET( trans_srcfile ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/${trans_file}.qrc)
SET( trans_infile ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${trans_file}.qrc)
SET( trans_outfile ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/qrc_${trans_file}.cxx)

# Copy the QRC file to the output directory, because the files listed in the 
# qrc file are relative to that directory.
ADD_CUSTOM_COMMAND(
    OUTPUT ${trans_infile}
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy ${trans_srcfile} ${trans_infile}
    MAIN_DEPENDENCY ${trans_srcfile}
    )

# Run the resource compiler (rcc_options should already be set). We can't
# use QT4_ADD_RESOURCES because the qrc file may not exist yet.
ADD_CUSTOM_COMMAND(
    OUTPUT ${trans_outfile}
    COMMAND ${QT_RCC_EXECUTABLE}
    ARGS ${rcc_options} -name ${trans_file} -o ${trans_outfile} ${trans_infile}
    MAIN_DEPENDENCY ${trans_infile}
    DEPENDS ${qm_files}
    )

# Add compiled resources to executable dependency list
ADD_EXECUTABLE( ${APP_NAME} ... ${trans_outfile} )
```

Use `${Qt5Core_RCC_EXECUTABLE}` instead of `${QT_RCC_EXECUTABLE}` if you use Qt 5.

Comment: Looks promising, I'll try that. +1

Comment: I've built your idea up from the beginning step by step to learn how you did it. Works perfectly.

Comment: Solid! Worked like a charm

Comment: Don't stop reading, there is a more simple way to do it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34798124/789427

Answer (score 6):

I have found a very simple way to do it in CMake 3.0 (and, maybe, earlier) without `ADD_CUSTOM_COMMAND` and other complications.

First, you should create a QRC file with all `.qm` files listed ( thanks, [the_fly_123](https://stackoverflow.com/users/545705/the-fly-123) ):

```
<RCC>
  <qresource prefix="/translators">
    <file>myapp_en.qm</file>
  </qresource>
</RCC>
```

Then you can copy this QRC file into the output directory using `configure_file` and use standard Qt routines to build and add it:

```
# Change lang.qrc to the name of QRC file, created on the previous step
set(lang_qrc "lang.qrc")
configure_file(${lang_qrc} ${lang_qrc} COPYONLY)
qt5_add_translation(myapp_QM ${myapp_TRANSLATIONS})
qt5_add_resources(myapp_QM_RC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${lang_qrc})
```

Then include `${myapp_QM_RC}` in `add_executable` along with other sources.
**Note:** For Qt4 replace all `qt5_` prefixes with `qt4_`

Comment: instead of `${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}` (the root build dir), it should be `${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}` (the subdir in build dir), because that is where [configure_file](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.10/command/configure_file.html) copies to.

Comment: awesome, this even takes away the need to disable the CLEAN_NO_CUSTOM property!

Answer (score 2):

My solution is to generate `ts.qrc` XML file with compiled translations from scratch and then complie it with app.

Here is example:

```
file(GLOB QRC_FILES *.qrc)
file(GLOB TS_FILES ts/*.ts)
...

# Option for updating translations
option(UPDATE_TRANSLATIONS "Update source translation ts/*.ts files (WARNING: make clean will delete the source *.ts files. Danger!)" OFF)
if(UPDATE_TRANSLATIONS)
qt4_create_translation(QM_FILES ${TS_FILES})
endif()
...
# Compiling translations *.ts -> *.qm
qt4_add_translation(QM_FILES ${TS_FILES})
...
# Create translations QRC file - ts.qrc
set(TRANSLATIONS_QRC "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/ts.qrc")
file(WRITE ${TRANSLATIONS_QRC} "<RCC>\n\t<qresource prefix=\"/ts\">")
foreach(QM_FILE ${QM_FILES})
    get_filename_component(QM_FILE_NAME ${QM_FILE} NAME)
    file(APPEND ${TRANSLATIONS_QRC} "\n\t\t<file alias=\"${QM_FILE_NAME}\">${QM_FILE_NAME}</file>")
endforeach()
file(APPEND ${TRANSLATIONS_QRC} "\n\t</qresource>\n</RCC>")
list(APPEND QRC_FILES ${TRANSLATIONS_QRC})
...
# Compiling *.qrc files
qt4_add_resources(QRC_SRCS ${QRC_FILES})
...
# Add compiled resources to executable dependency list
add_executable(${APP_NAME} ... ${QRC_SRCS})
```

File tree:

```
/ - source code root
/rc.qrc - contains app icons etc.
/ts/appname_*.ts - application translations
...
/build - build root
/build/appname_*.qm - compiled translations
/build/ts.qrc - translations rescources
/build/Release/qrc_rc.cxx - compiled icon etc. resources
/build/Release/qrc_ts.cxx - compiled translation resources
```

Files in `ts` dir initially generated by `lupdate` tool.

Comment: Good, but it doesn't work with parallel make (make -jSOMETHING)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Qt resources system to include your translation directly into your application binary. Use QT4_ADD_RESOURCES macro to do this. There is some example how to use it: http://www.qtcentre.org/wiki/index.php?title=Compiling_Qt4_apps_with_CMake

Comment: Yes I already figured that out. But it won't work: CMake 2.6 discoveres the sources of the QRC (in my case the to be generated QM file) but won't be able to know how to build this file as it expects it to be in the source path, not the build path (where it was created before).