# Compile .qm (i18n) files into binary

Tags: c++, qt, internationalization, qt5, qmake

I have multiple i18n qm files and translation works like a charm right now.
The problem I'm facing is, that I have the following folder structure:

```
project
-build
--debug
--release
-src
-i18n
```

Now my colleagues have different build folder structures, hence:

```
translator.load("../../i18n/{translationfile}");
```

won't work for them.
One solution might be to settle on a specific build-folder structure, but this is not what I want. I'd prefer to export all the translations to the application itself so it may be shipped without any special folder structure. Just give the customer the binary and go, like it should be.

Anyway, I have no idea how to do this in qmake (nor in cmake for that matter, but qmake is what I need to use here.)

I had a look at: [How to Integrate Qt4 qm files into binary using cmake and QRC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3125327/how-to-integrate-qt4-qm-files-into-binary-using-cmake-and-qrc) but still not sure.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I fixed it.

Instead of

```
translator.load("../../i18n/{translationfile}");
```

I use

```
QDir dir(":/i18n");
translator.load(dir.absoluteFilePath({translationFile}));
```

I also added a i18n.qrc file to my pro file:

```
RESOURCES += images.qrc \
             i18n.qrc
```

It works if I move the binary/executable to another folder and execute it from there, so I guess that's all that is needed to compile translation files into a QApplication.